# How can I add set action undo for this snackbar?

Tags: android

I'd like to add an "undo" feature for this snackbar that displays via checkbox..any ideas welcome, thanks

```
        check.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton c, boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked) {
                    Snackbar.make(c, R.string.snack, Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else {
                    Snackbar.make(c, R.string.snackbar, Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to set action:

```
Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar
                    .make(coordinatorLayout, "Message is deleted", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("UNDO", new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                           //Your Logic for undo
                        }
                    });

snackbar.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 check.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener(){
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged (CompoundButton c,boolean isChecked){
        SnackBar snackbar;
        if (isChecked) { 
            snackbar = Snackbar.make(c, R.string.snack, Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .setAction("undo", new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override 
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                            //do something here
                        }}); 
        } 
        else {
            snackbar = Snackbar.make(c, R.string.snackbar, Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT);
        }
        snackbar.show(); 
        } 
     }
```